# How to create route53 record for AWS Gateway API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, aws-route-table

I have existing hosted zone and `A` record in AWS route 53. The `A` record is pointing to cloudfront distribution.
lets say the hosted zone name is `abcd.ci.example.io`. The `A` record name is same as hosted zone. I can access the web site at `abcd.ci.example.io` without any issue.

I also have AWS Gateway API with invoke url `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev` I can access a particular API route from the browser using invoke url `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/v1/healthcheck`

I want to assign a custom domain name to invoke url. So I created a new CNAME record in the hosted zone as `api.abcd.ci.example.io` and set the value to `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev`

But then when I try to access a route using `https://api.abcd.ci.example.io/v1/healthcheck` I get error `This site can’t be reached`

A simple command line ping to `api.abcd.ci.example.io` also returns error as `Ping request could not find host api.abcd.ci.example.io. Please check the name and try again.`

Below is list of records in hosted. There are couple of acm validation records as well for both the domains.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before API Gateway will let you point your custom domain to it, you first have to setup the custom domain [in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html), which includes setting up the SSL certificate API Gateway will use for that custom domain.